# Change div order based on device from PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a video tutorial which will pull Video link, title, button, button link from a MySQL table.

For this, I have two Bootstrap `<div>`s to show from PHP loops, one `<div>` contains a button, a video and some content. Click on the button shows the video in VideoSrc `<div>` and a button of the currently selected `<li>` and hides others. It works fine, but a problem comes with arranging the stuff on mobile view.

My code is:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <ul class="list-unstyled video-tutorials no-margin">
        Video titles from loop start
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" iframesrc="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID" calltoaction="action_1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary magic">
            <span class="title">VIDEO_TITLE</span><i class="fa fa-play icon-bg "></i
          ></a>
        </li>
        Video titles from loop end
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="panel panel-default tutorials no-margin" style="min-height: 490px">
        <div class="panel-body no-padding">
          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe id="videoSrc" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
          </div>
          Video Content from loop starts
          <a href="VIDEO_BUTTON_LINK" id="action_VIDEOID" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow calltoaction" target="_self">VIDEO_BUTTON_TITLE</a>
          Video Content from loop ends
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, it shows Buttons and Content `<div>`s side by side, so its fine on computer view.

But on mobile, first it shows all the buttons in `col-md-5` `<div>` and then shows the content `col-md-7` `<div>`. So, for every selected button, one has to scroll down to see the VIDEO of the selected button. So, what I am looking to do is to show the selected VIDEO directly under the clicked button.

Any thoughts on this?